# URL structure for tags for SEO

Tags: seo, tags

What is the best structure on tag URL for google SEO?

For example:

```
example.com/tags/episode/black
example.com/tags/episode/green

example.com/tags/course/black
example.com/tags/course/green
```

or

```
example.com/episode/tags/black
example.com/episode/tags/green

example.com/course/tags/black
example.com/course/tags/green
```

Comment: Have you even tried a cursory search of this site? This question comes up frequently.https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/52406/subcategorising-for-url-structure https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/92241/advice-on-url-structure https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ from a 30 second search... And I know there are more.

Comment: Does that question have anything to do with my question?

Comment: Why use the word "tags" in the URL at all.  Why not `/course/course-name` without "tags"?

Comment: Sorry. question edited.

Comment: Even with your edit, why use "tags"?   Why not `/course/black`?

Comment: Why do you use tags and categories?`black` is my tag name